# Details in retopology

Tags: mesh, topology

I'm doing a retopology of a skull. In some areas, the model appears through the retopology mesh. For this reason, i think i'm making too many faces, so it fits perfectly. Am I doing right? Also, I've read something about baking, and i don't know if it's only for texture.

So, for example: what should i do in that incision?

Notes: subsurf and shrinwrap mods are on

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could continue to retopologize over this incision. 
When your retopology is over, you would UV unwrap it, and do some displacement map baking, or normal map baking.

Then you can use the baked displacement (or normal map) textures on your retopologized model. So the incision would not be in the topology, but in the texture (normal map, or displacement). So it would be visible in your render.

Comment: And should i make bigger faces in retopology, or it is ok?

Comment: I think it mainly depends on what you want to do with your model. If it is for real time display or gaming, you could try bigger faces (to reduce the polycount). If performance is not an issue here, you could go with small faces, as the result would be better.

Comment: And you should also consider if just keeping the highpoly model is an option for you (for instance if you only do a render of this object in a simple scene, then do you really need to get a good topology ?).